# Why is my controller redirecting to show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rake routes I get:

```
project_todos GET    /project_todos(.:format)                   project_todos#index
                            POST   /project_todos(.:format)                   project_todos#create
           new_project_todo GET    /project_todos/new(.:format)               project_todos#new
          edit_project_todo GET    /project_todos/:id/edit(.:format)          project_todos#edit
               project_todo GET    /project_todos/:id(.:format)               project_todos#show
                            PUT    /project_todos/:id(.:format)               project_todos#update
                            DELETE /project_todos/:id(.:format)               project_todos#destroy
project_todos_toggle_status POST   /project_todos/toggle_status(.:format)     project_todos#toggle_status
```

from:

```
resources :project_todos

  post "project_todos/toggle_status"
```

I have a line in my view that looks like:

```
<%= link_to 'Toggle Project', project_todos_toggle_status_path(id: todo.id), method: "post" %>
```

That results in a link that looks like:

`http://localhost:3000/project_todos/toggle_status?id=1`

and results in the following error:
[image]

Which is weird in that it goes to the show action, and I don't understand why or how it sets the id = toggle_status.

Any ideas on how I can make this work? I've done something very similar in the past using a static_pages controller would that make any difference?

**Updates:**

development.log:

```
Started GET "/project_todos/1/toggle_status" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-21 12:08:09 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/project_todos/1/toggle_status"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

routes.rb

```
resources :project_todos do
    member do
      post :toggle_status
    end
  end
```

view code:

```
 <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <li class="todo_item todo"><%= todo.title %></li>
    <%= todo.id%>
    <%= link_to 'Toggle Project', toggle_status_project_todo_path(todo), method: "post" %>
<% end %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require tinymce
//= require_tree .
```

**Update #2**

Could errors like this cause this issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to "toggle_status" for a single resource ProjectTodo, correct? A more common way to describe this route in Rails 3 would be follows:

```
resources :project_todos do
  member do
    post :toggle_status
  end
end
```

This yields a deterministic order in your routes file:

```
toggle_status_project_todo POST   /project_todos/:id/toggle_status(.:format) project_todos#toggle_status
             project_todos GET    /project_todos(.:format)                   project_todos#index
                           POST   /project_todos(.:format)                   project_todos#create
          new_project_todo GET    /project_todos/new(.:format)               project_todos#new
         edit_project_todo GET    /project_todos/:id/edit(.:format)          project_todos#edit
              project_todo GET    /project_todos/:id(.:format)               project_todos#show
                           PUT    /project_todos/:id(.:format)               project_todos#update
                           DELETE /project_todos/:id(.:format)               project_todos#destroy
```

allowing you to write in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Toggle Project', toggle_status_project_todo_path(@todo), method: "post" %>
```

which would post to "http://localhost:3000/project_todos/1/toggle_status"

Comment: That url looks correct, but I get the following error: `No route matches [GET] "/project_todos/1/toggle_status"` Why is it trying to do a get?

Comment: Check the link_to and the routes file matches what I have. What's the output on your log/development.log file when you click the link? I'm testing on Rails 3.2.7. Also, check your js assets, if you're using jquery, I believe you should be including jquery_ujs to make the method post functionality work.

Comment: I've updated above and done a copy-paste so it's exactly what I have. The only change I've made is @todo to todo for obvious reasons.

Comment: I have recreated this in a separate app and it works, so what else could it be?

Comment: Looking at the URL as generated from html I get: `<a href="/project_todos/1/toggle_status" data-method="post" rel="nofollow">Toggle Project</a>` So how can figure out between clicking the link and getting the error what the issue is?

Comment: Glad the button_to worked. To use link_to, you'll need to enhance the page with javascript. Are you using jquery? In your application.js file, you should have //= require jquery and //= require jquery_ujs

Comment: Yeah, I have both in my application.js as indicated above. I had it working with a default 3.2.8 rails install with on setting up the routes, adding the toggle_status action, and adding the link to the view. I didn't even look at the application.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `project_todos` line above the `resources: project_todos` line in your routes.rb

Then the custom route will be found before the id version.

Comment: I think it did need to be moved, but nothing has changed and I restarted rails so it would grab the new route.

Comment: You could try adding it as a collection route to the project_todos resources - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions